# replace a variable

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to replace the value of a variable from an HTML form.

in my config.php

I have a variable

$ num = 3;

I want when I type a value on the form form.html will replace the value 3.

Here is my HTML form :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr align="center">
    <td>num</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="num"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Your `<input>` needs to be in a `<form>` tag. Then use `$num = $_POST['num'];`  Use `intval($_POST['num'])` if it must be an integer.

Comment: This is _very_ rudimentary. I recommend you spend some time reading [the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Comment: You want to replace a variable in PHP with the value of something that's submitted via a form?

Comment: It does not work, the variable does not take the value we assign ...Here is my config.php <?php /* ========================================================================= General settings for language and database ========================================================================= */ $number = $_POST['num']; echo($num); define("MAILQUEUE_BATCH_SIZE",$num); ?> –

Answer (score 0):

Trying to replace 1 particular variable in a seperate php file on the submit of a form is a really bad way to do it. If this configuration variable is something that you want to be able to be changed, why not store it in a database table? It's then much easier to update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it in a `<form>` tag, then set the `method="post"`.

The PHP code will be : `$num = $_POST['num'];`

Comment: It does not work, the variable does not take the value we assign ...Here is my config.php <?php /* ========================================================================= General settings for language and database ========================================================================= */ $number = $_POST['num']; echo($num); define("MAILQUEUE_BATCH_SIZE",$num); ?> – –

Comment: you have `$number` instead of `$num`

Answer (score 0):

Once you've submitted the form, the values from the form will be available either through the `$_GET` or `$_POST` global arrays, depending upon the submit method of the form you have used.  Assuming that you used `post` as your form's method, you would set `$num` as follows:

```
$num = $_POST['num'];
```

Your full HTML (and PHP) page should look like this:

```
<html>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $num = intval($_POST['num']);
}
?>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr align="center">
            <td>num</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: It does not work, the variable does not take the value we assign ...Here is my config.php <?php /* ========================================================================= General settings for language and database ========================================================================= */ $number = $_POST['num']; echo($num); define("MAILQUEUE_BATCH_SIZE",$num); ?> – –

Comment: It isn't a persistent solution. Once the user has navigated away from the page with the form, `$num` will be `null`.

Comment: Yes.exactly .. So what you are proposing ?/

Comment: Store it in a database, or use `$_SESSION` / `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

form file:

```
<html>
<body>

  <form action='action.php' method='post'>
    <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
      <tr align="center">
        <td>num</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="num"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<?php
  $num = (int)$_POST['num'];
?>
```

Comment: The user wants to assign the value of `$_POST['num']` to `$num`. Not assign the value `3` to `$_POST['num']`. Your `method` attribute is also invalid, there should be no underscore prepended to the string.

Comment: Yes ,exactly that's true i want to assign the value of $_POST['num'] to $num .

Comment: Then you might want to check my answer... ;-)

Comment: sorry, fast typing. Edited the answer.

Comment: It does not work, the variable does not take the value we assign ...Here is my config.php <?php /* ========================================================================= General settings for language and database ========================================================================= */ $number = $_POST['num']; echo($num); define("MAILQUEUE_BATCH_SIZE",$num); ?> –

Comment: @user1581854 You are assigning $_POST to `$number` not `$num`